# Why is this not making a plus sign?

Tags: php

I have:

```
$str = 'test%2B';
echo html_entity_decode($str);
```

I want it to return `test +`

What am I doing wrong?

NOTE: Sorry, the string cannot be modified.  It's from an external source, I just need to make it replace the %2B with + signs somehow with PHP.

Comment: It is returning the string back exactly as it already is

Answer (score 6):

You didn't escape the space, and you should be using [`urldecode`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php) instead of [`html_entity_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php).

Try

```
$str = 'test%20%2B';
echo urldecode($str); // test +
```

If you wish to use `html_entity_decode`, use `&#43;`:

```
$str = 'test &#43;';
echo html_entity_decode($str); // test +
```

EDIT: If you need to decode a url that you cannot change yourself, `urldecode` should still work fine.

Answer (score 2):

That string is encoded for a URL, not with HTML entities.

You need [`urldecode`](http://php.net/urldecode).

```php
echo urldecode($str); // "test +"
```

An HTML-encoded string would look like this: `test +`, because none of those characters need HTML-encoding.

Answer (score 0):

Try `&#43;` instead.  In your example, you are using URL encoding syntax and not HTML entity syntax.

Answer (score 0):

In html a `+` is `&#43;`. Try

```
$str = 'test &#43;';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = "test %2B";
echo urldecode($str);
```